# How to allow two ember-cli services to cross communicate?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Using ember-cli version 0.0.42

Run these commands

```
ember new myApp
cd myApp
ember generate service serviceOne
ember generate service serviceTwo
ember generate controller application
```

Make these updates

**controllers/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        var a = this.get('serviceOneService.testFunction');
    }
});
```

**initializers/service-one-service.js**

```
export default {
    name: 'service-one-service',
    initialize: function(container, app) {
        app.inject('route', 'serviceOneService', 'service:service-one');
        app.inject('controller', 'serviceOneService', 'service:service-one');
    }
};
```

**services/service-one.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    testFunction: function(){
        //How would I make a call to serviceTwo.testFunction here instead of returning 123
        return "123"
    }
});
```

**services/service-two.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    testFunction: function(){
        return "Test function from service 2"
    }
});
```

My question is how to I inject serviceOne into service two and serviceTwo into service one. One I do that how do I access service two from service one.  Inside when calling I have an idea of how to injest the service directly into all controllers but when I try and inject into another object (service) inside of testFunction "this" refers to the window and not an ember object.

My first thought was to just inject each service into the overal service namespace but I get this message:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot inject a `service:service-one` on other service(s). Register the `service:service-one` as a different type and perform the typeInjection.
```

Comment: Are you to trying to inject the services into each other?

Answer (score 4):

You can inject one service into the other by defining an initializer and setting setting the `after` property to something like `after: ['service-one', 'service-two']`, which would cause it to run after both of those services have been registered.

The initializer would look something like...

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  after: ['service one', 'service two'],
  name: 'service injections',
  initialize: function(container, application){
    application.inject('service:service-one', 'serviceTwoService', 'service:service-two');
  }
});
```

Unfortunately if you then try to inject `service:service-one` into `service:service-two` you'll get an error stating `Maximum call stack size exceeded` which happens because the container ends up in a loop while trying lookup all the needed injections.

You can see a working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fitaka/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the jsbin. I have this setup inside of my ember-cli project but am not sure how to get a reference to ServiceTwoService when my ServiceTwoService looks like this: `import Ember from 'ember'; export default Ember.Object.extend({ testFunction: function(){ //How would I make a call to serviceTwo.testFunction here instead of returning 123 return "abc"; } })`

So I am able to make it into service one, but when I try and this.get('serviceTwoService').testFunction(); This refers to Window and not to an Ember Class, so it says Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

Comment: Your running into a scope issue, but unless you are saving a reference service ones `testFunction` the `this` inside should refer to service one. Can you reproduce in a bin?